# CGWindowListCreateImage produces broken image

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, xquartz

**Objective**: I want to periodically make a window screenshot in OSX.

Following the Apple guides i've managed to build simple working code which captures window content very well. However, the problem is that approximately 1 of 50 pictures gets distorted for some reason.

I'm using **CGWindowListCreateImage** function in order to periodically capture window content, but it keeps producing garbage from time to time.

this is my simple code:

```
CGImageRef img = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull,
                                         kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow,
                                         wc->window.window_id, wc->image_option);
if (!img)
    return;

char path_str[1024];
snprintf(path_str, 1023, "/tmp/obs/image%llu.png", ts);

// here is just output image to file "as is"
CFURLRef path =
        CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL,
                                      __CFStringMakeConstantString(path_str),
                                      kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);

// file/format to save pixels to
CGImageDestinationRef destination =
        CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(
                path, CFSTR("public.png"), 1, NULL); //[4]

// add our captured pixels
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, img, nil);

// generate the image
if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
    printf("Failed to finalize\n");
}
```

I ran test for different apps and windows, so result looks like this:

#### A good picture (what i expect from code above)

[image: A good picture (what i expect from code above)]

#### Broken picture (such picture is being captured with chance ~ 1/50)

[image: Broken picture (such picture is being capture with chance ~ 1/50)]

What i already tried:

- to play with parameter **CGWindowImageOption**
- to use **CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray** instead
- to output image to the screen, i saw the same results.
- build up **CGImageRef** upon on file, instead of capturing using **CGWindowListCreateImage** - works ok.

  Used config:

  - macOS 10.13.6
  - XQuartz 2.7.11
  - CoreGraphics 2.0

At this point i'm guessing **CGWindowListCreateImage** is buggy or something. Did anyone see something similar?

Comment: I have also strange results, but for me the window captures are diagonal like offset, very strange. Still no solution for it.